# JavaScript + Spring MVC + Gson, не выводит поля объекта (undefined)

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, json

У меня с контроллера:

```
public @ResponseBody String getMenus(@RequestBody PlaceJson placeJson){
    List<Menu> menus = menuService.getAllFromPlace(placeJson.getId());
    List<MenuJson> menu = new ArrayList<MenuJson>();
    for(Menu menu1: menus){
        menu.add(new MenuJson(menu1.getId(), menu1.getName()));
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(menu);
    return json;
}
```

Отправляется на JSP JSON, все приходит правильно, вот пример респонса: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На стороне клиента, Ajax'ом я хочу вывести этой объект просто методом alert(). Пробовал двумя способами:
1)

```
$.ajax({

    url : "/caferacer/menu/menus",
    contentType : 'application/json',
    data : JSON.stringify(PlaceIdJson),
    type : 'POST',
    success : function(data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(obj.id + ", "+obj.name);
    }
```

И второй способ:

```
$.ajax({

    url : "/caferacer/menu/menus",
    contentType : 'application/json',
    data : JSON.stringify(PlaceIdJson),
    type : 'POST',
    success : function(data) {
        var obj = data;
        alert(obj.id + ", "+obj.name);
    }
```

И в одном и в другом в аллерте получаю андефайн. Кто может сказать, где ошибка?

**Update1**: Можно ли записать этот массив в menus?

```
        var menus = $.map(arr, function(el){return el;});
        var table = $('#field');
        $('#field').empty();
        $(menus).each(function(i, menu){
            $('<tr/>').appendTo(table).append($('<td/>').text(menu)).append($('<a onclick="remove('+menu+')" /><td/>').text('remove'));
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получаете вы массив, а работать пытаетесь как будто получили один объект.
Нужно выбирать конкретный элемент для вывода

```
alert(obj[0].id + ", "+obj[0].name);
```

где `obj[0]` - это первый элемент массивa.

либо в цикле идти по всему массиву

```
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
    console.log(obj[i].id + ", "+obj[i].name);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Данный код не делает ничего:

```
var menus = $.map(arr, function(el){return el;});
```

`menus` - это массив с теми же элементами что и `arr`

Так что в `each` можно использовать сразу `arr`

```
$.each(arr,function(i, menu){
    $('<tr/>').appendTo(table)
              .append(
                  $('<td/>').text(menu)
              )
              .append(
                  $('<a onclick="remove('+menu+')" /><td/>').text('remove')
              );
});
```

И так как вы получаете массив - да, вы можете его использовать в этом коде.

Comment: а как можно преобразовать этот массив в один объект или как правильно? в json ?  просто запутался уже.
чтобы я мог обращаться к нему таким образом: obj.id, obj.name.

Comment: @Khodan.D. обновил ответ, но вообще все зависит от того, что вы хотите дальше с ним делать. можно было сразу `console.log(obj)` делать. чтобы посмотреть что пришло

Comment: @Khodan.D., так как массив - это коллекция элементов, а вы хотите конкретный элемент. вам нужно выбрать какой именно элемент из массива вы хотите

Comment: @Khodan.D., отредактируйте вопрос. в комментариях код проблематично разбирать

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Khodan.D., обновил ответ

Comment: все, я разобрался с ответом. Все работает. Спасибо.